# bootstraptable queryparams using array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

when i was using bootstraptable and try to paginate server-side,i came across a problem that i should send a array to server.

usually in jquery ajax ,i use 'traditional:true' to get desired effect.

but in bootstraptable it seems that there isn't such choice.

`$('#detailTable').bootstrapTable({
        url: 'service.jsp',
        columns: coloumns,
        pagination: true,
        sidePagination: 'server',
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
        pageList: [10, 20, 30],
        responseHandler: function (data) {
        },
        queryParams: function (params) {
            var pageNumber = params.offset / params.limit + 1;
            return {
                pageModule: 'WrJson_GetProvDetails',
                params: [servType, startTime, endTime, city, pageNumber, params.limit],
            };
        }
    });`

using this ,the server will not receive the proper params as the key 'params' will be added a '[]'.

so is there any solutions or alternatives available?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

after some researching in bootstraptable api,I found an option named 'ajaxOption'.

```
$('#detailTable').bootstrapTable({
  ajaxOption:{traditional:true}
})
```

then an array param can be used properly..